# reinstall nginx if i delete /etc/nginx in centos server how to reinstall it again i am new in centos and nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

**i install nginx in my remote server but i done some error in my nginx.conf file and could not able to revert back**
so it tried to remove my nginx and reconfigure it 
so i used these step which is given in the link to delete my nginx
http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-remove-uninstall-nginx-on-centos-7-rhel-7-oracle-linux-7/

then i use
 **yum remove nginx** and again reinstall it
but when i try 
**sudo systemctl start nginx** or **[root@lotto nginx]# service nginx start** 
its showing 
**Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exit`enter code here`ed with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details**.
when i am using 
**[root@lotto nginx]# systemctl status nginx.service**

showing

nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-07-01 07:48:44 EDT; 18s ago
  Process: 30832 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30830 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14307 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto nginx[30832]: nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto nginx[30832]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Jul 01 07:48:44 lotto systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
and **[root@lotto nginx]# journalctl -xe**

nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server

   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-07-01 07:48:44 EDT; 18s ago
  Process: 30832 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30830 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14307 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Answer (score 6):

- uninstall

  `yum remove nginx`
- install

  In CentOS , you should using `yum install`  ; instead of `apt-get install` in Ubuntu.

Comment: when i use sudo yum purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full<br> it showing <br>Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No such command: purge. Please use /bin/yum --help

Comment: but could not able to start nginx service again

Answer (score 0):

> at last I found out the solutions by my self

I used `nginx -t` which shows that I don't have any syntax error in my code

Then I use

```
user nobody; // in my nginx.conf
```

This solved my problem

Thanks everyone for your help!